# How to separate caught errors based on their OPCODE (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

So basically, I have a bot that part of its functionality is to create channels inside of a guild (discord server.) I have the generic error handlers, and catch blocks, but what I am wondering is how to separate the error 'Maximum number of guild channels reached (500)' of opcode '30013,' so that if that is the error, it display a message saying the maximum amount of channels has been created, as well as allowing for the other errors to get caught.

Ideally all errors can still get caught, but if the error is the desired error, it will do what I ask, instead of simplifying the error JSON response, like the error handler make it do.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but, you shouldn't use error handling as a means of program work flow. As best as possible, so long as it's in your control you should avoid errors where possible. I say this based on the example you gave, if you know the max channels that can be created is 500, you should check the current channel count before creating a new channel. Inform the user of the limit if creating a new one would exceed that limit. This way you don't have to catch the error. Errors that you should catch are those that you have no control over and cannot check for in advance.

Comment: ^ You can simply check `guild.channels.size` and avoid the error altogether.

Comment: @slothiful @Anu6is The idea isn't that I am using it to control workflow, but I understand what you're saying. What you suggest is already what I have, however, occasionally there will be instances where if the server is as 499 channels, and 2 people simultaneously attempt to create a channel by chance, it will return the error, and will not send the "capacity" message that I have incorporated with `guild.channels.size`

Comment: @Timesis It would indeed send the message, just for whichever user's command is run second.

Comment: @slothiful I know from first hand that it doesn't, as occasionally, whether its due to my poor coding, choice of VPS, or discord API, that it will return the error instead of the message, if this didn't happen, I wouldn't be here making this post.

Comment: lol, fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something alone these lines should work if the error response received matches [this link](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#json-example-json-error-response).

```js
try {
    // You code here
}
catch(err) {
    if (err.code == 30013) {
    // feedback code here
    }
}
```

As I'm not sure if you are using async or not I'm presenting the standard `try/catch` format vs `.catch`. Regardless the logic should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the error object and see what property distinguishes it from others (most likely its `code` property). Once you know, check the property in your catch block against the desired one. If it matches, continue with your specific code.

Comment: How would one do this?